Why is there discrepancy in the result with matlab and python?
I want to solve the 1-D transient heat transfer equation.
Define a 1-D geometry (a line) in y-direction
dT/dt = (k/(rho*cp))*d²T/dy²

I.C.: @t=0, temperature of all elements is 25°C
B.C.: The geometry is divided into several elements.

The bottom element is exposed to hot roller -kdT/dy = h(T_roller-T)

The upper element is exposed to atmosphere -k*dT/dy = h(T-T_ambient)


But I am getting different results in the Matlab file and Python file.
The radiation boundary condition works perfectly for both of the files, but the roller in the contact boundary condition produces different results. The results differ by 4-5°C when the temperature of the roller is low and the difference increases to about 10-11°C when the temperature of the roller increases by 100°C.
Matlab code:
function pde()
% Constants

Ny = 1000;            % Number of spatial grid points
Nt = 5000;           % Number of time steps
velocity_x = 15/60; % line speed in m/s
% Thermal properties of different layers
layer1_thickness = 0.001;  % Thickness of layer 1 (meters)
layer1_k = 2.15;            % Thermal conductivity of layer 1 (W/m-K)
layer2_thickness = 0.001;  % Thickness of layer 2 (meters)
layer2_k = layer1_k;            % Thermal conductivity of layer 2 (W/m-K)
rho_1 = 1950;           %density of layer 1 (kg/m³)
rho_2 = 1950;           %density of layer 2 (kg/m³)
cp_1 = 2100;            %specific heat capacity of layer 1 (J/kg-K)
cp_2 = 2100;            %specific heat capacity of layer 2 (J/kg-K)
T_roller = 120;         %Temperature of hot roller (°C)
h_roller = 500;         %Convective heat transfer coefficient (W/m2-K)



Ly = layer1_thickness+layer2_thickness;         % Total thickness of the system (meters)
% Ambient temperature and convection properties
T_ambient = 25;    % Ambient temperature (°C)
h_air = 12;        % Convective heat transfer coefficient of air (W/m²-K)

%Discretization in space
ny1 = ceil(layer2_thickness/Ly*Ny);
ny2 = Ny-ny1;

y1 = linspace(0,layer2_thickness,ny1);
y2 = linspace(layer2_thickness,Ly,ny2);
y = [y1,y2(2:end)];

% Initialize temperature matrix
initial_temperature1 = 25;
initial_temperature2 = 25;

radiative_flux = 150e3;
absorption = 50;
performance = 80;
Net_radiative_intensity = radiative_flux*(absorption/100)*(performance/100);

dia_roller = 0.5;                   %diameter of hot roller (m)
contact_angle = 180;                %contact angle/wrap angle for hot_roller in °

y_1 = pi*dia_roller*contact_angle/360;              %in contact with hot roller
y_2 = 1.3;                                          %after hot roller


t1 = y_1/velocity_x;
t2 = y_2/velocity_x;


T = t1+t2;

nt1 = ceil(t1/(t1+t2)*Nt);
nt2 = Nt-nt1;


t11 = linspace(0,t1,nt1);
t12 = linspace(t1,t1+t2,nt2);



%pdepe settings
m = 0;  %for 1-D cartesian coordinates with no symmetry
phase = 1;
sol = pdepe(m,@pdefun,@icfun,@bcfun,y,t11);
u1 = sol(:,:,1);
phase = 2;
sol = pdepe(m,@pdefun,@icfun,@bcfun,y,t12);
u2 = sol(:,:,1);


plot([t11,t12],[[u1(:,1);u2(:,1)],[u1(:,25);u2(:,25)],[u1(:,50);u2(:,50)]])
grid on
function [c f s] = pdefun(y,t,u,dudy)
  if y <= layer2_thickness
    c = rho_2*cp_2;
    f = layer2_k*dudy;
    s = 0;
  else
    c = rho_1*cp_1;
    f = layer1_k*dudy;
    s = 0;
  end
end
function u = icfun(yq)
  if phase==1
    if yq <= layer2_thickness
      u = initial_temperature1;
    else
      u = initial_temperature2;
    end

  else
    u = interp1(y,u1(end,:),yq);
  end
end
function [pl ql pr qr] = bcfun(yl,ul,yr,ur,t)
  if phase==1
    %pl = -h_roller*(ul-T_roller); %% in contact with roller at bottom element
    pl = Net_radiative_intensity; %% radiation at bottom element
    %pl = -h_air*(ul-T_ambient);
    ql = 1;   
    pr = h_air*(ur-T_ambient);
    %pr = -Net_radiative_intensity;   
    qr = 1;

  else
    pl = -h_air*(ul-T_ambient);
    ql = 1;
    pr = h_air*(ur-T_ambient);
    %pr = -Net_radiative_intensity;
    qr = 1;
  end
end
end

Result:
Matlab_radiation_bottom_element

Matlab_roller_contact_bottom_element

Python code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
Ny = 1000           # Number of spatial grid points
Nt = 5000         # Number of time steps
velocity_x = 15 / 60  # Line speed in m/s

# Thermal properties of different layers
layer1_thickness = 0.001  # Thickness of layer 1 (meters)
layer1_k = 2.15          # Thermal conductivity of layer 1 (W/m-K)
rho_1 = 1950              # Density of layer 1 (kg/m³)
cp_1 = 2100              # Specific heat capacity of layer 1 (J/kg-K)

layer2_thickness = 0.001  # Thickness of layer 2 (meters)
layer2_k = 2.15           # Thermal conductivity of layer 2 (W/m-K)
rho_2 = rho_1             # Density of layer 2 (kg/m³)
cp_2 = cp_1               # Specific heat capacity of layer 2 (J/kg-K)

T_roller = 120           # Temperature of hot roller (°C)
h_roller = 500           # Convective heat transfer coefficient (W/m²-K)

T_ambient = 25           # Ambient temperature (°C)
h_air = 12               # Convective heat transfer coefficient of air (W/m²-K)

Ly = layer1_thickness + layer2_thickness

# Discretization in space
ny1 = int(np.ceil(layer2_thickness / Ly * (Ny)))  
ny2 = Ny - ny1
                                        
y1 = np.linspace(0, layer2_thickness, ny1)
y2 = np.linspace(layer2_thickness, Ly, ny2 + 1)[1:]   
y = np.concatenate((y1, y2))


# Initial condition function
def icfun(y, ny1, ny2):
    u_initial = np.zeros_like(y)
    u_initial[:ny1] = 25  # Temperature for layer 2
    u_initial[ny1:] = 25  # Temperature for layer 1
    
    return u_initial


# Initial condition
initial_condition = icfun(y, ny1, ny2)


def pdefun(t, u):
    dudt = np.zeros_like(u)
    
    # Internal nodes for layer 2
    for i in range(1, Ny-1):
       
        if y[i] <= layer2_thickness:  # Layer 2
            dudt[i] = layer2_k / (rho_2 * cp_2) * (u[i+1] - 2*u[i] + u[i-1]) / (y[i-1] - y[i])**2
           
        else:  # Layer 1
            
            dudt[i] = layer1_k / (rho_1 * cp_1) * (u[i+1] - 2*u[i] + u[i-1]) / (y[i-1] - y[i])**2
    
    # Boundary conditions
    if t <= t1:
        #dudt[0] = layer2_k / (rho_2 * cp_2) * (u[1] - u[0]) / (y[1] - y[0])**2 - h_air / (rho_2 * cp_2) * (u[0] - T_ambient) / (y[1] - y[0])
        #dudt[0] = layer2_k / (rho_2 * cp_2) * (u[1] - u[0]) / (y[1] - y[0])**2 - h_roller / (rho_2 * cp_2) * (u[0] - T_roller) / (y[1] - y[0])     ##in contact with roller at bottom element
        dudt[0] = layer2_k / (rho_2 * cp_2) * (u[1] - u[0]) / (y[1] - y[0])**2 + Net_radiative_intensity / (rho_2 * cp_2 * (y[1] - y[0]))           ##radiation at bottom element
        dudt[-1] = layer1_k / (rho_1 * cp_1) * (u[-2] - u[-1]) / (y[-1] - y[-2])**2 - h_air / (rho_1 * cp_1) * (u[-1] - T_ambient) / (y[-1] - y[-2])
        
        
    else:
        dudt[0] = layer2_k / (rho_2 * cp_2) * (u[1] - u[0]) / (y[1] - y[0])**2 - h_air / (rho_2 * cp_2) * (u[0] - T_ambient) / (y[1] - y[0])
        dudt[-1] = layer1_k / (rho_1 * cp_1) * (u[-2] - u[-1]) / (y[-1] - y[-2])**2 - h_air / (rho_1 * cp_1) * (u[-1] - T_ambient) / (y[-1] - y[-2])
        
        
        
    return dudt



# Solve the PDE
dia_roller = 0.5
contact_angle = 180

radiative_flux = 150e3
absorption = 50
performance = 80
Net_radiative_intensity = radiative_flux*(absorption/100)*(performance/100)

y_1 = np.pi * dia_roller * contact_angle / 360
y_2 = 1.3

# Discretization in time
t1 = y_1 / velocity_x
t2 = y_2 / velocity_x
T = t1 + t2
t_eval = np.linspace(0, T, Nt)
sol = solve_ivp(pdefun, (0, T), initial_condition, method='BDF', atol=1e-4, rtol=1e-4, t_eval=t_eval)

# Extract the solution
u = sol.y.T

# Plot results
plt.plot(t_eval, u[:, 0], label='Temperature at bottom surface')
plt.plot(t_eval, u[:, ny1], label='Temperature at interface')
plt.plot(t_eval, u[:, -1], label='Temperature at upper surface')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.legend()

# Set x-ticks at a step of 1 second
x_ticks = np.arange(0, int(T) + 1, 1)  # Range from 0 to T (rounded up) with a step of 1 second
plt.xticks(x_ticks)

# Set y-axis limits dynamically based on the minimum and maximum values of u[:, 0] and u[:, -1]
y_min = min(np.min(u[:, 0]), np.min(u[:, -1]))
y_max = max(np.max(u[:, 0]), np.max(u[:, -1]))

# Round down y_min to the nearest multiple of 5
y_min = np.floor(y_min / 5) * 5 - 5

# Round up y_max to the nearest multiple of 5 plus 5
y_max = np.ceil(y_max / 5) * 5 + 5

# Set y-axis limits
plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)

# Define y-ticks with a step of 5°C within the y-axis limits
y_ticks = np.arange(y_min, y_max, 5)
plt.yticks(y_ticks)
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()

Results:
Python_radiation_bottom_element

Python_roller_contact_bottom_element

I tried to check whether the time points are defined exactly or not and checked with radiation boundary condition which works alright. But the strange behaviour is that the curve shape or behaviour is the same.
The area of interest is the inclusion of roller boundary condition at bottom element in python code (dudut[0]) gives different result as compared to the boundary condition at left element/bottom element(pl).
Below, you can see the comparison of results in matlab and python when the total time steps is 100 and number of divided elements across the total thickness is 1000.
difference in results of python and matlab
Could anyone please help or suggest how can I resolve this discrepancy?

Can you explain what exactly your FOUR graphs represent and what exactly is the difference (i.e. between which pair of graphs) you are concerned about. Also, in the text of your question you almost certainly require -k.dT/dy (the internal heat flux), not k.dT/dt (which is not directly to do with the boundary condition)

@lastchance - thanks a lot for pointing out the mistake.I have edited the code and kept those commented lines in the boundary conditions for the bottom element(python code) dudt[0] so that you can check, once it can be tried with convective boundary condition using a roller and the other is the radiation boundary condition.

As far as I can see, the Python convective boundary conditions are correct, but I can't tell whether the radiation part is or is not, because I can't see whether you mean radiative intensity to be inward (raising T) or outward (lowering T) - just check the sign on that. I'm afraid I'm not qualified to comment on your Matlab code. Are there any related problems you could compare with. I'm sure that you could compare related computations withose given in the classic heat-transfer text books (e.g. Incropera and de Witt).

@lastchance - thankyou for your reply. The radiation is inward(increasing T) and the radiative boundary condition is working fine as it is a constant. But the convective boundary condition is not working fine in python code as compared to the matlab code. I have also put the code for the comparison. The matlab code is correct as it matches with the real process. I couldnot comprehend why the python code gives the temperature few °C less than the matlab although the path and behaviour is similiar. I need help on that to debug it. I am sorry that I havenot explained it in a good manner.

How do you know that the matlab code is correct? Both codes give similar physical behaviour. Can you check the heat fluxes in and out of the boundary cells by hand? Also, why don’t you plot the matlab results directly against the Python ones (use gnuplot or something similar). I’m not convinced that they give the same result even for radiation condition at the bottom boundary. You could also check convection alone simply by starting with a high initial temperature and letting the domain cool.

@lastchance - As I already told, this is a real life problem statement and I checked the matlab model with the actual process behaviour of a drying of a film on a roller and it matched.
I am sorry but I couldn't understand fully the checking of heat fluxes in and out of boundary by hand and gnuplot.
Yes, for radiation they give the same result and thatswhy i have given the plots, you could also check them yourself. If I choose high initial temperature in the python for convective boundary condition, then it will somehow match but it loses the whole point of simulating the case then.

if you want to compare Matlab and Python results then plot them on the SAME graph, not two different graphs with two different scales. You do not have to plot graphs in Matlab or Python only, just export the data and plot them in some graphing package. If you have the exported data you can also calculate the heat fluxes -k.dT/dy (discretised the same way as in your code).

Your Matlab code, @Adya, has just 51 grid points in the y direction. Your Python code has 1000. This will significantly affect the fraction of the layer affected by either boundary condition. The problem seems unlikely to be directly with your convective boundary condition, since convective heat transfer is very weak here. (Eventually, after time t1, the temperature must decay to ambient (25C) and that has clearly not happened within the timescale plotted here. I have no way of running your Matlab code, but I suggest that you make the grid spacings match.

@lastchance - thankyou for the reply. I have again edited the code and now everything is same and plotted the graph using same scale. Unfortunately, I do not have an idea about graphing package so I put two graphs differently but I think you can observe the difference in temperature when roller is contact with bottom element. It should decay to 25°C but it cannot attend that temperature within that time t12(matlab) or t1+t2(python)
I tried to print the values separately by reducing the number of elements but the temperature has a difference of 1.5°C or so afer 10th or 11th time step, strange!

Your implementation of boundary conditions is slightly wrong. Because your node is precisely on the boundary you should either use ghost nodes or, equivalently, take the width of the end cells to be only half the internode spacing. Effectively, this ends up multiplying all your boundary du/dt values by 2. However, this makes negligible difference to the Python solution as the dy values are very small. I think your Matlab solution is probably the wrong one and I would guess that it is using too large a time step. Can you control the maximum time step in the Matlab solver?

actually, i do not focus on ghost nodes or on the interface condition as i treat it as a whole product and only focus on the edge of the product. I believe the python boundary condition is somewhat wrong as you can see the deviation in the very early stage in the picture. Unfortunately, Matlab model is correct and it matches with the real process as well as the simulation done on other few softwares. Yes, i can control the maximum time step in matlab solver but it doesn't resolve the current issue.

I have now written a Fortran code to solve the same diffusion problem in the rise phase for the case (commented in your Python) where the lower boundary is determined by roller. The only tiny issue with your Python boundary conditions is that the dudt[0] and dudt[-1] values should be multiplied by 2 (or divided by 1/2) since the effective thickness associated with heat storage in the end node is (1/2)dy, but this makes negligible change to the results. My Fortran agrees entirely with your Python. Your Matlab code is at fault.

Your Matlab function is at fault. You have muddled up the ur and ul values at the left (l) and right (r) boundaries. I can reproduce this error in my Fortran code (given below) if I fake the source terms at the boundaries.
Where you have
pl = -h_roller*(ur-T_roller); %% in contact with roller at bottom element

it should be
pl = -h_roller*(ul-T_roller); %% in contact with roller at bottom element

(i.e. ur should be replaced by ul).
Where you have
pr = h_air*(ul-T_ambient);

it should be
pr = h_air*(ur-T_ambient);

(i.e. ul should be replaced by ur).
I wrote a Fortran code to do the simple diffusion equation in the rise phase (up to t1=PI). It agrees with your Python solution in this phase (but note my earlier comments about applying a factor 2 to both your dudt[0] and dudt[-1] to accommodate the fact that the end node only controls a width (1/2)dy. If you can run Fortran then you can simulate your Matlab error by uncommenting the lines indicated.
!============================================================================================================
!                du       d2u
! Solve   rho cp --  -  k ---   =  source   (where source comes from boundary fluxes replacing diffusive flux)
!                dt       dy2
!
! The source term is written as    S + Sp.u     where Sp should be negative for stability
!
! Use Crank-Nicolson timestepping (average flux and source over "old" and "new" times)
!
! Discretise in the form
!         A_i u_i-1 + B_i u_i + C_i u_i+1 = D_i
! and solve by the tri-diagonal matrix algorithm at every timestep.
!
!============================================================================================================
program diffusion
   use iso_fortran_env, only: real64
   implicit none

   integer, parameter :: N = 1000
   integer, parameter :: Nt = 5000

   real(real64), dimension(N) :: A, B, C, D, u

   real(real64) :: dy =  0.002 / ( N - 1 )
   real(real64) :: rho = 1950.0
   real(real64) :: cp = 2100.0
   real(real64) :: k = 2.15
   real(real64) :: T_roller = 120.0
   real(real64) :: T_air    = 25.0
   real(real64) :: h_roller = 500.0
   real(real64) :: h_air = 12.0
   real(real64) :: dt = 3.14159 / Nt

   integer      j
   real(real64) t
   real(real64) kfac, tfac
   real(real64) SL, SR, SPL, SPR

   ! The correct boundary conditions (in the rise phase)
   SL = h_roller * T_roller;   SPL = -h_roller
   SR = h_air    * T_air   ;   SPR = -h_air

   kfac = k * dt / ( rho * cp * dy ** 2 )
   tfac = dt / ( rho * cp * dy )

   A = -0.5 * kfac;   A(1) = 0;   A(N) = -kfac
   C = -0.5 * kfac;   C(N) = 0;   C(1) = -kfac

   open( 10, file="u.out" )
   u = T_air
   t = 0.0

   do j = 1, Nt
      t = t + dt

!         ! If you want to fake the error in your Matlab solution, uncomment the lines below
!         SL = h_roller * ( T_roller - u(N) );   SPL = 0
!         SR = h_air    * ( T_air    - u(1) );   SPR = 0

      B = 1 + kfac;   B(1) = B(1) - tfac * SPL;   B(N) = B(N) - tfac * SPR
      D(2:N-1) = u(2:N-1) - 0.5 * kfac * ( -u(1:N-2) + 2 * u(2:N-1) - u(3:N) )
      D(1) = u(1) - kfac * ( u(1) - u(2  ) ) + tfac * ( SL + SL + SPL * u(1) )
      D(N) = u(N) - kfac * ( u(N) - u(N-1) ) + tfac * ( SR + SR + SPR * u(N) )
      call tdma( A, B, C, D, u )
      write( 10, "(3(1x,es12.4))" ) t, u(1), u(N)

   end do

contains

   subroutine tdma( A, B, C, D, X )
      !******************************************************************************
      ! Solve, using the Thomas Algorithm (TDMA), the tri-diagonal system
      !     A_i X_i-1 + B_i X_i + C_i X_i+1 = D_i,     i = 1, n
      !
      ! Effectively, this is the n x n matrix equation.
      ! a(i), b(i), c(i) are the non-zero diagonals of the matrix and d(i) is the rhs.
      ! a(1) and c(n) are not used.
      !******************************************************************************
      real(real64), intent(in ) :: A(:), B(:), C(:), D(:)
      real(real64), intent(out) :: X(:)

      integer n
      integer i
      real(real64), allocatable :: P(:), Q(:)
      real(real64) denominator

      n = size( D )
      allocate( P(n), Q(n) )
      X = 0

      ! Forward pass
      i = 1
      denominator = b(i)
      P(i) = -c(i) / denominator
      Q(i) =  d(i) / denominator
      do i = 2, n
         denominator = b(i) + a(i) * P(i-1)
         if ( abs( denominator ) < 1.0e-10 ) return
         P(i) =  -c(i)                   / denominator
         Q(i) = ( d(i) - a(i) * Q(i-1) ) / denominator
      end do

      ! Backward pass
      X(n) = Q(n)
      do i = n - 1, 1, -1
         X(i) = P(i) * X(i+1) + Q(i)
      end do

      deallocate( P, Q )

   end subroutine tdma

end program diffusion

Output (corresponds to your 4th graph; i.e. the second python graph). Note that, in the interest of simplicity and to find your original error, I have only integrated as far as t=t1. The latter phase can be continued simply by amending the source terms after this point.


thankyou for the input but as far as I have experienced it till now that the matlab model is not wrong as it is consistent with the simulation given by ansys for the real time process. Even I was testing for other cases so I found that when the stations are like this: roller-air-radiation-air , then radiation gives deviation in result.
In a nutshell, I cannot say matlab is wrong as it is producing results in coherence with ansys which produces result similiar to real time process.

Yes, apart from the specific boundary conditions of this case the Matlab model probably worked well. There will be no problem with a radiation condition because the expressions for pl and pr do not involve ul and ur. However, look carefully at the Matlab code you posted: you have pl (incorrectly) based on ur and pr (incorrectly) based on ul. i.e. boundary fluxes are set to depend on the wrong surface temperatures. Once you correct these then the Matlab and Python codes will probably agree completely.

with bottom element it should be pl , as it considers either the left element when considered in x-direction or bottom element in y-direction. so the code is correct as it is given. I also have tried different cases and got the exact result as predicted by ansys but the python gives the deviation in result.

@Adya, one last time: pl should depend on ul, not on ur. You can see that from the second of the expressions that you have commented out there. Whether your variable is called x or y is completely irrelevant. This is my last input to this thread as you are clearly unwilling to believe me.

I am very sorry, I got the error what you are trying to convey.
